# Activiti TimerBoundaryEvent times out immediately

Tags: spring, activiti

I have an application that uses Activiti version `5.22.0` and Spring `4.2.0` and for some reason `TimerBoundaryEvent`s time out instantly on one of my linux servers, here's what `uname` says:

`linux 2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.x86_64`

At the same time, everything works perfectly on windows machines and other linux servers, which are almost identical.

The timer is attached to `ReceiveTask`. Time duration is set to `PT15M`.

Does anyone know what can possibly trigger the timer to not wait at all? I realize that the question is quite broad, but not sure what information can help narrow that down, so if anyone knows what can be useful -- please let me know, I'd gladly provide any info. Thank you!

Comment: DId you figure it out? Same issue here.

Comment: Yes, turned out we had 2 instances of application connected to the same database, which were competing for the events, and these 2 applications were in 2 different timezones with about 8 hours difference, so when one instance had set a timestamp to a time that had already passed for another instance, that another instance updated the status to timed out